# Reuse Time Machine backup drive after migration to new machine - revisited

Tags: macos, time-machine, migration

The answer by tubedogg to question [Reuse Time Machine backup drive after migration to new machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255744/37797) described a procedure to do this.  It didn't address this issue:

```
JT-imac:/Users/jt>> sudo tmutil associatedisk -a "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" "Volumes/IoTMBU/Backups.backupdb/Latest/Macintosh HD"
/Users/jt/Volumes/IoTMBU/Backups.backupdb/Latest/Macintosh HD: Not a snapshot volume.
```

Stupid typo or fouled up TM BU drive?

Comment: Typo. You're missing a forward slash; `"Volumes/IoTMBU…` should be `"/Volumes/IoTMBU…`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a / from the start of your second path, so it's looking in the current directory for Volumes, as shown by the error "/Users/jt/Volumes/…". Add a / to the start of the second path.

Comment: Added it, but same message:-(

Comment: @JT Exactly the same or can you paste the new command and response into your question a second time?

Comment: sudo tmutil associatedisk -a "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" "/Volumes/IoTMBU/Backups.backupdb/Latest/Macintosh HD"
Password:
/Volumes/IoTMBU/Backups.backupdb/Latest/Macintosh HD: Not a snapshot volume.
JT-imac:/Users/jt>>

Comment: drive had been named "Iomega  TM BU" - changed name back again but no change even after eject and re-attach.

Comment: thanks everyone, but I gave up and reformatted, losing my history:-(